# Column Insertion from 2 Table to Table 1

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I have 2 tables:

**checkinout**

```
Userid | Checktime | Checktype | VERIFYCODE | SENSORID | Memoinfo | WorkCode | sn |
```

**userinfo**

```
Userid | Name | Gender
```

I want to get the column Name only from userinfo table and insert it to checkinout table corresponds to their Userid, `checkinout.userid=userinfo.userid`

Below is my query but I'm getting syntax error around userinfo, can you tell what I'm missing?

> Syntax Error: unexpected 'userinfo' (identifier)

```
SELECT checkinout.USERID, checkinout.CHECKTIME, checkinout.CHECKTYPE,checkinout.VERIFYCODE, checkinout.SENSORID, checkinout.Memoinfo, checkinout.WorkCode, checkinout.sn, userinfo.name 
from bio_raw.checkinout, bio_raw.userinfo
join bio_raw.userinfo
on checkinout.userid = userinfo.userid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not mix explizit and implizit join:

```
SELECT checkinout.USERID, checkinout.CHECKTIME, checkinout.CHECKTYPE,checkinout.VERIFYCODE, checkinout.SENSORID, checkinout.Memoinfo, checkinout.WorkCode, checkinout.sn, userinfo.name 
   from bio_raw.checkinout
   join bio_raw.userinfo
   on checkinout.userid = userinfo.userid
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
  cio.`userid`,
  cio.`checktime`,
  cio.`checktype`,
  cio.`memoinfo`,
  cio.`sensorid`,
  cio.`sn`,
  cio.`verifycode`,
  cio.`workcode`,
  ui.`name`,
  ui.`gender` 
FROM
  checkinout cio 
  INNER JOIN userinfo ui 
    ON ui.`userid` = cio.`userid`
```

Answer (score 1):

In the line `from bio_raw.checkinout, bio_raw.userinfo`, remove the `, bio_raw.userinfo`

- When using `JOIN` no need to mention more than one table name in the `FROM`.
- I added Table alias names `CI`, `UI` for better readability.

The working code will be:

```
SELECT CI.USERID
    ,CI.CHECKTIME
    ,CI.CHECKTYPE
    ,CI.VERIFYCODE
    ,CI.SENSORID
    ,CI.Memoinfo
    ,CI.WorkCode
    ,CI.sn
    ,UI.NAME
FROM bio_raw.checkinout AS CI
JOIN bio_raw.userinfo AS UI ON CI.userid = UI.userid
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to join 2 tables there is no need to put all of them in `FROM` param.

```
SELECT checkinout.USERID, checkinout.CHECKTIME, checkinout.CHECKTYPE,checkinout.VERIFYCODE, checkinout.SENSORID, checkinout.Memoinfo, checkinout.WorkCode, checkinout.sn, userinfo.name 
   from bio_raw.checkinout
   join bio_raw.userinfo
   on checkinout.userid = userinfo.userid
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `userinfo` table to be mentioned in `FROM` clause. Use the below query and I believe it should work:

```
SELECT checkinout.USERID, checkinout.CHECKTIME, checkinout.CHECKTYPE,checkinout.VERIFYCODE, checkinout.SENSORID, checkinout.Memoinfo, checkinout.WorkCode, checkinout.sn, userinfo.name 
from bio_raw.checkinout
join bio_raw.userinfo
on checkinout.userid = userinfo.userid;
```